# Lemmatization of pandas column using Wordnet after POS

Tags: python, nlp, pandas, python-3.x

I have a pandas column `df_travail[line_text]` with text.

I want to lemmatize each word of this column.

First I Lowercase the text :

```
df_travail ['lowercase'] = df_travail['line_text'].str.lower()
```

Then, I tokenize it and apply POS (because of wordnet default configuration which consider every word as noun).

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
tok_and_tag = lambda x: pos_tag(word_tokenize(x))
df_travail ['tok_and_tag'] = df_travail['lowercase'].apply(tok_and_tag)
```

Then I have the following : (extract of the entire `df_travail['tok_and_tag']`)

```
"[('so', 'RB'), ('you', 'PRP'), (""'ve"", 'VBP'), ('come', 'VBN'), ('to', 'TO'), ('the', 'DT'), ('master', 'NN'), ('for', 'IN'), ('guidance', 'NN'), ('?', '.'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('this', 'DT'), ('what', 'WP'), ('you', 'PRP'), (""'re"", 'VBP'), ('saying', 'VBG'), (',', ','), ('grasshopper', 'NN'), ('?', '.')]"
[('actually', 'RB'), (',', ','), ('you', 'PRP'), ('called', 'VBD'), ('me', 'PRP'), ('in', 'IN'), ('here', 'RB'), (',', ','), ('but', 'CC'), ('yeah', 'UH'), ('.', '.')]
```

However, then, I'm lost about the lemmatization function to apply (with Wordnet), in order to take into account the fact that I applied POS ?

Comment: Hi Alex, I would recommend looking at lemmatizers from Spacy (https://spacy.io/api/lemmatizer) and Stanza (https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/lemma.html) for more accurate results. They models are trained on some very large corpuses and are available in a bunch of languages.